# How to create a AEM Search component

Tags: search, aem, sightly, aem-6

How to create a AEM Search component.
I need the logic and code for the following parts.

1. Search component HTL code for Input and Results.
2. Model code for searching the "fulltext" using QueryBuilder.
3. Clientlib (if any).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all readily available as part of the open-source [Core Components Search](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/tree/master/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/search/v1/search):

- Component [HTL/Sightly script](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/search/v1/search/search.html)
- Sling Model [interface](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/bundles/core/src/main/java/com/adobe/cq/wcm/core/components/models/Search.java) and [implementation](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/bundles/core/src/main/java/com/adobe/cq/wcm/core/components/internal/models/v1/SearchImpl.java)
- [Servlet](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/bundles/core/src/main/java/com/adobe/cq/wcm/core/components/internal/servlets/SearchResultServlet.java) for loading results
- Client-side [JS](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/search/v1/search/clientlibs/site/js/search.js) and [CSS/LESS](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/search/v1/search/clientlibs/site/css/search.less) code